# remove background behind rounded corner

Tags: android

I am trying to make a bottom sheet with a rounded background but there is always a white background behind it

android v21

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="create_notes.BottomSheet"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp16"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/foreground"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_layout">
 //....
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/foreground"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dp24" android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dp24"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your style.xml

```
 <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog_bg</item>
    </style>
```

java class add style

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(InstaActivity.this, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme);
```